# Python 3: Read input until -1 is input

Tags: python, input

In Python, I would like to read integers until -1 is input.

Example input:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, -1 # (Commas indicate new entries)
```

Desired effect:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10]
```

Additional note:
Could you do this concisely with list comprehension?

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: nums = [input() for i in range(int(input())) if input() != -1]

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Python 3 - just edited title

Comment: Are the commas part of the actual input?

Comment: No they are not in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while loop`.

**Ex:**

```
inVal = input("Enter Num: ")

res = []
while int(inVal) != -1:    #Break loop if user enters -1
    res.append(inVal)
    inVal = input("Enter Num: ")
print(res)                 #Print user entered numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the example input will be a single string and comma delimited.

```
nums = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40,55,60,-1"
nums = nums[:nums.index(",-1")].split(",")
nums = [int(x) for x in nums]
```

This will find the index of the "-1" element and cut off the result. Then list comprehension to cast all the strings to ints, this part is optional if you're okay with storing it as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have comma separated values you could do something in the lines of:

```
from itertools import takewhile

s = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40,55,60,-1'

g = takewhile(lambda x: x != '-1', s.split(',')) #generator

list(map(int,g)) # convert str to in
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. What I did here is, I created an empty list and kept appending values to it unless the input was -1. Hope this will help you

```
choice = int(input("Enter Numbers: "))
nums = []

while choice!= -1:
 nums.append(choice)
 choice = int(input("Enter Numbers: "))

print(nums)
```